# Formatting a Date/Time in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, timezone

I have a date/time string that looks like the following:

```
Wed Sep 21 2011 12:35 PM Pacific
```

How do I format a DateTime to look like this?

Thank you!

Comment: I use this guy's cheat sheet all the time: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: Is it *always* Pacific? Because I don't believe the .NET DateTime formatting will give you the time zone *name*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bit before the time zone is easy, using a [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
string text = date.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm t");
```

However, I believe that the .NET date/time formatting will *not* give you the "Pacific" part. The best it can give you is the time zone *offset* from UTC. That's fine if you can get the time zone name in some other way.

A number of `TimeZoneInfo` identifiers *include* the word Pacific, but there isn't one which is just "Pacific".

Comment: Isn't it kind of redundant to give 24 hour time and the AM/PM? :P

Comment: +1, and an offset of -8 may not always mean Pacific - many named zones share the same offset, and DateTime/DateTimeOffset don't store it.

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, doh. Of course it's possible that it still *is* 24 hour - we can't tell. (There's already redundancy in the format with the name of the day of the week of course.)

Comment: @Paul: You're preaching to the choir :) Having said that, even Noda Time wouldn't have just "Pacific" as a time zone ID...

Answer (score 6):

```
string.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm tt"), TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);
//Result: Wed Sep 07 2011 14:29 PM Pacific Standard Time
```

Trim off the Standard Time if you do not want that showing.

**EDIT:**
If you need to do this all over the place you can also extend DateTime to include a method to do this for you.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.MyCustomToString());
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string MyCustomToString(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm tt"), TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName).Replace(" Standard Time", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

You can run this example in LinqPad with a straight copy and paste and run it in Program mode.

**MORE EDIT**

After comments from below this is the updated version.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.MyCustomToString());
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string MyCustomToString(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm tt} {1}", DateTime.Now, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName).Replace(" Standard Time", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to mix String.Format and ToString at the same time. You can do it all in one call: `String.Format("{0:ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm tt} {1}", DateTime.Now, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName)`

Comment: Oh, whoops. The `HH` should be `hh` for 12-hour time.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the docs about [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Note this may be a bit crude, but it may lead you in the right direction.

Taking and adding to what Jon mentioned:

```
string text = date.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm t");
```

And then adding something along these lines:

```
    TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
    string x = localZone.StandardName.ToString();
    string split = x.Substring(0,7);
    string text = date.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm t") + " " + split;
```

I haven't tested it, but i hope it helps!