# C# Date Time Formatting

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert my `DateTime` object to this kind of date format:

1. Mmm dd yyyy
2. dd Month yyyy

I am currently doing object.GetDateTimeFormats('D')[1].ToString()

This is giving me January 31, 2012. But I should be able to get these two things:

1. Jan 31, 2012
2. 31 January, 2012

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: [GetDateTimeFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01cf75zk.aspx) returns an array of strings (all supported forms).  Is this what you're trying to do?  Why not call `date.ToString('dd MMM yyy')` or `date.ToString('MMM dd yyyy')` if those are the two you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7176580/352101; http://stackoverflow.com/q/7340621/352101;http://stackoverflow.com/q/2151744/352101......

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a custom `DateTime` formatting string:

```
// Returns Jan 31, 2012
myDateTimeObject.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");

// Returns 31 January, 2012
myDateTimeObject.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy");
```

All of the custom date/time formats are [listed here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

All types of [date formatting you need.](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Just select the correct string format you need:

- MMM - gives you Jan, Feb, Mar
- MMMM - gives you January, February, March

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MMM-yy"));
```

18-Jan-18

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MM-yy"));
```

18-1-18

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MM-yyyy"));
```

18-1-2018

**MoreDetails** :- 
http://www.code-sample.net/CSharp/Format-DateTime

Answer (score 1):

To get the Format like  - September 26, 2019

```
string.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", YourDate);
```